# ImageButton in Android homescreen widget

Tags: android, widget, selector, imagebutton, homescreen

I have a homescreen widget with an imagebutton. I have the button working with a pending intent, but I can't seem to figure out how to change the button image when it is pressed.

I tried using a selector and it works in my widget test activity, but not in the remoteview.

How could I implement this functionality in the  home screen widget?

Comment: Hi Josh,
Did you finf a way for getting this press state stay?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can set a different Image within your remote view.

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.buttonimg, "setImageResource", R.drawable.button_on);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by moving the selector inside it's own XML file and putting in res/drawable and then referencing that xml file as my resource for my imagebutton in the app-widget's layout xml.

**buttonimg.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
 android:state_pressed="false"
 android:drawable="@drawable/button_off" />
<item
 android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/button_on" />
<item  
 android:drawable="@drawable/button_off" />
</selector>
```

**widget_layout.xml**

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/buttonimg"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_x="0px"
android:layout_y="2px"
android:clickable="true"
android:src="@drawable/button"
>
```

I now have a different problem, however. The selector only allows me to change the image onPress. On release, the image changes back >:-(

How do I get the image state change on press and stay in that state until next press (like the ToggleButton)?

Comment: that's what a selector is supposed to do.  after you have released the button you must change the image programmatically...  look at the above answer